# Getting error "Program failed due to missing install location" by windows app Cert kit

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, nsis

I was created the installer file by NSIS tool then I tried to verify by windows app cert kit. It always returns error like "Program failed due to missing install location" but I mentioned installer location on NSIS settings.

Please give me good solution for this,

Thank you in advance
Jey

Comment: Do you have a test report like you can see @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/05/26/leveraging-windows-7-client-software-logo-toolkit-to-test-your-application.aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Windows® 7 Client Software Logo 
Technical Requirements & Program Eligibility](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/9/1E9580D9-2B2B-499C-918A-C9BA5EAC4A32/Windows%207%20Client%20Software%20Logo.xps) document you will see a list of required uninstall registry values:

- DisplayName
- InstallLocation
- Publisher
- UninstallString
- VersionMajor (or MajorVersion)
- VersionMinor (or MinorVersion)

You can probably just set InstallLocation to the value of $InstDir:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YourAppnameOrGuid" "InstallLocation" "$InstDir"
```

Comment: hi,
Thank you for your answer. Now I am getting error like Uninstall.exe fails because it is not marked manifested.
User facing shortcuts (Desktop or Start Menu) must be able to run as a Standard User e.g. “asInvoker”.
If any of the above files are manifested with uiAccess set to "True", you must request a waiver. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The application you are creating shortcuts to needs a "UAC manifest" with the level set to "asInvoker" ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929 )